# JBoss AS 6 and Log4j

Tags: jboss, log4j, jboss6.x

I know there are plenty of posts out there on this topic, but I am not finding any of them helpful or relevant.

I have a simple requirement. I am moving from JBoss AS 4.0.4 to JBoss AS 6. In my 4.0.4 environment I have a log4j.xml in server/myconfig/conf folder, and log4j.jar in server/myconfig/lib. I realise that JBoss AS 6 has changed to a native logging framework. We are heavily dependent on log4j and changing is not practical. I have seen many posts saying to package log4j jar and the log4j.xml file in your application. I have dozens of jar and war files in deploy and lib. Would I seriously be expected to package the log4j.jar and log4j.xml into all of them? I would hope not, so maybe setting -Djboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false will help? But I still see people saying to put log4j.jar and log4j.xml into ear/war files even with that set.

If someone could please tell me how I can mimic my 4.0.4 set up please.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: have you actually tried deploying the log4j jar separately, just the .jar. I'd think that would work, since "JBossAS6 by default uses shared CL domains aka "big-ball-o-mud"." ([source](https://community.jboss.org/thread/167745))

Comment: @eis Yes, I have log4j.jar in server/<config>/lib. I have log4j.xml in server/<config>/conf and have defined the file appender with file name serverX.log, but the file that appears is server.log. So it is using JBoss's native logging as defined in (I guess) server/deploy/jboss-logging.xml.

Comment: that's not exactly what I meant. If you have it in server/lib, you're using it from a shared class path. What about using it as a deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to package log4j jar inside your application.

Do the below things :

1.) Set the following parameter in Standalone.conf.bat file 
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false

2.) make one module for log4j. inside the modules folder for log4j. For reference you can check other folder that are already there.

3.) Make one jboss-deployment-structure.xml place it inside web-inf folder.
The file will contain the below thing

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <include>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </include>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

It will include the log4j jar in your application.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply. I do not know what Standalone.conf.bat is (or its Linux equivalent, as that's the platform I'm on). But in my jboss start script, I have already set -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false. So I think I have your step (1) covered. As for step (2), I do not know what you mean by a "modules" folder. A Jboss installation has no such folder as far as I'm aware. Would you therefore be kind enough to elaborate on what you mean by steps (2) and (3). Thank you.

Comment: As you have installed jboss in your linux environment. So go to your $JBOSS_HOME, it should contain the modules folder.

Comment: I believe you are talking about JBoss 7. I am using JBoss 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Log4J on Jboss 6.1 without any problems.

Never had to include the Log4J jar anywhere, seems to be included (checking this, I found it under `client/lib`).

The only special thing I had to do, is to integrate my Log4J configuration into `server/<config>/deploy/jboss-logging.xml` (layout is pretty similar to a `log4j.xml`).

After that I just use `org.apache.log4j.Logger` inside my classes and everything works as expected.

Comment: How you used Logger in Java Side ?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss automatically injects the APIs for log4J 1.2, SLF4J, common-logging and java.util.logging.  Do **NOT** package it with the application.

You can add the logging configuration to: *serverDirectory\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml* (or whichever configuration you choose to use).

Below is the section to add your logging configuration (JBoss EAP 6):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.3">
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: This question is for JBoss AS6, not EAP6.